# What is the justification for going from $\frac{d(v^2)}{dt}dt$ to $d(v^2)$ in this derivation regarding work in the presence of kinetic friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, work, differentiation

I do not understand what is being done in the last line of the quote, where we manipulate one integral to get another.

> Incorporating Newton's second law $\Sigma\mathbf{\vec{F}}=m\mathbf{\vec{a}}$ gives $$\Sigma W_{\text{other forces}}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{r}}=\int m \mathbf{\vec{a}}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{r}}=\int m\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{v}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{r}}=\int^{t_f}_{t_i}m\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{v}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot\mathbf{\vec{v}}\ \mathrm{d}t\tag{8.12}$$ where we have used Equation 4.3 to rewrite $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{r}}$ as $\mathbf{\vec{v}}\ \mathrm{d}t$. The scalar product obeys the product rule for differentiation, so the derivative of the scalar product of $\mathbf{\vec{v}}$ with itself can be written $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\mathbf{\vec{v}}\cdot\mathbf{\vec{v}}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{v}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot\mathbf{\vec{v}}+\mathbf{\vec{v}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{v}}}{\mathrm{d}t}=2\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{v}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot\mathbf{\vec{v}}$$We used the commutative property of the scalar product to justify the final expression in this equation. Consequently, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{v}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot\mathbf{\vec{v}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\mathbf{\vec{v}}\cdot\mathbf{\vec{v}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}v^2}{\mathrm{d}t}$$ Substituting this result into Equation 8.12 gives $$\Sigma W_{\text{other forces}}+\int\mathbf{\vec{f}}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\vec{r}}=\int^{t_f}_{t_i}m\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}v^2}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}m\int^{v_f}_{v_i}\mathrm{d}\left(v^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2_f-\frac{1}{2}mv^2_i=\Delta K$$

Comment: Please type everything out instead of posting pictures

Comment: Extending Aaron's comment, we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to see it as a change of variable (you may know it as "u-substitution"):

If $v^2=v^2(t)$ we have:

$$\text{d}(v^2)=\frac{\text{d}(v^2)}{\text{d}t}\text{d}t$$

Which is exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in two ways:

1) either you interpret it as a change if variable in the integral, i.e. you have a function of $t$, $v^2(t)$, and you recognize that $\frac{dv^2}{dt}dt$ is nothing but its differential $dv^2$

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{dv^2}{dt} dt =\int_{v^2(t_1)}^{v^2(t_2)}dv^2=v^2|_{v^2(t_1)}^{v^2(t_2)} =v^2(t_2)-v^2(t_1)$$

Or

2) you see it as the integral of the derivative which is simply the function $v^2(t)$ evaluated in the extrema of integration;

The first explanatiion probably gives you the insight you asked for;